# jQuery :contains in .not() doesn't work

Tags: jquery, contains

I've got this, but it doesn't seem to do anything, but I can't figure out why...syntax seems fine.

```
$('#entries li').not(function() {
    return $('span.date:contains("March 2016")', this);
}).hide();
```

In another function I use:

```
$('#entries li').not(function() {
    return $('.date', this).text() === formattedDate;
}).hide();
```

And that one works fine.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just use the working solution then `._.`

Comment: What's your HTML look like?

Comment: Well do you have an element that matches this: `span.date:contains("March 2016")` in your HTML?

Comment: @Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy showed what I needed to do was use is(). Solved it. jo8691 - the two are actually doing subtly different things and not interchangeable :-) stackErr - yep element was present. Answer below was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$('#entries li')` this one is very similar to

```
$('#entries li').not(function() {
    return $('span.date:contains("March 2016")', this);
}).hide();
```

Because you are returning a truthy value inside of the call back all the time. You have to use `.is()` function at this context to accomplish your task.

```
$('#entries li').not(function() {
    return $('span.date', this).is(':contains("March 2016")');
}).hide();
```

Or simply,

```
$('#entries li span.date:contains("March 2016")').hide();
```

Comment: Thanks. is() worked.
Not sure about your last example though as I'm trying to hide everything BUT entries that contain the date. But other one worked perfectly.

Comment: @Funktion Yeah. You can use the second variant now. I just made a typo there. You wanted to hide span.date that contains the data "March 2016". Right?

Comment: Yep...and the is() worked perfectly. Sorted. thanks.